# How to find rows between two dates per row

Tags: sql, date, count, window-functions, presto

I have the following table:

```
topic_id conversation      logical_date         start_date        end_date        type
1            1           2020-01-01 09:00    2020-01-01 09:00  2020-01-01 09:50 phone call
1            2           2020-01-01 09:14                                         text
1            3           2020-01-01 10:27                                         text
2            1           2020-02-03 08:40                                         text
```

This table represents support requests. Each support request has topic and topic has 1 or more conversations.

I want to find all text requests that were being done between start_date and end_date of phone call.

So for the above table I want to see:

```
topic_id conversation_id start_date            end_date        sum
 1            1           2020-01-01 09:00 2020-01-01 09:50     1
```

The logic is:
For each topic_id, type='phone call' take start_date  and end_date 
    compare them to type='text' conversations from this topic_id
    sum those who their logical_date between start_date and end_date

I know i need to do this with window function but I'm not sure how.

This is what I have so far:

```
select topic_id, conversation_id, start_date, end_date, count(1 ) over partition by () 
from table
where type = 'phone call'
```

I'm using Presto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'text' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.conversation_id = t.conversation_id and
                    t.logical_date between t2.start_date and t2.end_date and
                    t2.type = 'phone'
             );
```

If you actually want information from both records, use `join`:

```
select tt.*, tp.*
from t tt join
     t tp
     on tp.conversation_id = tt.conversation_id and
        tt.logical_date between tp.start_date and tp.end_date and
        tp.type = 'text' and
        tp.type = 'phone';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a correlated subquery to count how many `'text'` records can be found for the same `topic_id` for each `'phone call'` record:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select count(*)
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.topic_id = t.topic_id
            and t1.type = 'text'
            and t1.logical_date >= t.start_date
            and t1.logical_date <  t.end_date
    ) cnt
from mytable t
where t.type = 'phone call'
```

For performance, you want an index on `(topic_id, type, logical_date)`.

I'm not so sure that this is simpler done with window functions.